# html form select option with php to keep selected value active "notice undefined index"

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to implement an item selection drop down list that will store the selected value into an array for php to process into a query.

Using this:

```
<select name="FLexA" width="300" style="width: 30%">    
    <option value=" "> </option>
    <option value="1" <?= $_POST['FLexA'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection item 1...</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $_POST['FLexA'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection item 2...</option>
    </select>
```

returns "Notice : Undefined index ..." on FlexA

While Using the notice error handler "@" as below works fine but as I can remember, it was working without when I first used it on the form without the @ error handler.

```
<select name="FLexA" width="300" style="width: 30%">
<option value=" "> </option>
<option value="1" <?= @$_POST['FLexA'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection item 1...</option>
<option value="2" <?= @$_POST['FLexA'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Selection item 2...</option>
</select>
```

Can someone advise even if I get where I need, I'd like to understand what's behind the curtain for this.

Comment: Are you running this script to display the initial form, before the user has submitted anything?

Comment: Don't use [suppresses operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) its not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<?php` and `?>` open and close php tags

Also use `if(isset($_POST['customName']))` to ensure that they exist, as @user1844933 suggests.

Comment: If he's getting PHP errors, he must have the short tags option enabled, so this isn't the problem.

Comment: done with php tag, <?php=$_POST['FLexA'] ...did it. Thanks for your help

Comment: by the way, I'm not a php expert (but I start to feel good with the basics) nor web script expert, if I ever wanted multiple select dependant validation list like 2 or 3, is there a way to load everything from a simple text file colon separated data on the root folder into an associative array? I can do that but when the user sleects the first drop down list, must I switch to javascript to manage this event and populate the second drop down based on the choice of the first drop down? If yes, can javascript access the php associative array?

Comment: Javascript can access all the elements in the client side, and modify them. I recommend you to learn basic Javascript and JQuery library. The file that you say (*colon separated data*) is probably a JSON object, and yes, you can check `json_decode()` php function. Whish it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
 if(isset($_POST['FLexA'])) { 
   //your code
 }
```

Comment: My guess would be that this is right. I haven't done PHP in a while but I know `@` supresses warnings and I guess PHP will complain if you assume a key is in an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this script to display the initial form and also process form submission, the `$_POST` variables are only set when the user submits the form. When he first goes to the page, he's not submitting anything, so there are no `$_POST` variables, and you get warnings about undefined indexes.

If this wasn't happening before, someone probably changed the error reporting setting in php.ini so that it now shows notices.

You should change your tests to:

```
isset($_POST['FlexA']) && $_POST['FLexA'] == "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your PHP-within-HTML more concise you may consider creating a function:

```
<?php
function selected($key, $val){
    if(array_key_exists($key, $_POST)){
    print(($_POST[$key] == $val) ? " selected" : "");
    return true;
    }
return false;
}
?>

<select name="FLexA" width="300" style="width: 30%">    
    <option value=" "> </option>
    <option value="1"<?php selected("FLexA", "1"); ?>>Selection item 1...</option>
    <option value="2"<?php selected("FLexA", "2"); ?>>Selection item 2...</option>
</select>
```